# android grid layout size

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have been testing my program in different devices, but the layout is always different. this is the xml for the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counterView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/counterView"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="8"
    android:textSize="50dp" />


<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/numberPad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/passwordField"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/two" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/three" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/four" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/five" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/six" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/seven" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/eight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"

        android:text="@string/nine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnZero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="addInput"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plantBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:onClick="plantBomb" />
</GridLayout>
```

[image: on my phone]

[image: other phones]

the 3rd column seems to be having a different width, how can i fix that problem?
some of the devices are using android 4.x and above.

**EDIT**
tried it on a larger devices and the output is like this [image]

Comment: Have you tried setting your button's width to `match_parent`?

Comment: it doesnt work, the first button would just fill up the width and the other button would be hidden

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use from layout folder

for example :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // 470dp x 320dp //layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // 426dp x 320dp //layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       //640dp x 480dp // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml     // 960dp x 720dp  // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Comment: is it possible to give me a little bit of information about how it works? this is my very first android app

Answer (score 0):

Ok

You can create folders with their sizes for all size manually in each set.

Consider the following image:

[image]

Comment: is the size of the device is the actual problem? because i tried to make a Virtual device with different screen size, and it works just fine

Comment: Yes, but can also make use of other ways, but I think this is the right way.

Comment: all i need to do is to create the folder and copy and paste the xml into it right? theres nothing i needa add or change specifically ?

Comment: Yes ,is not difficult.

Comment: thanks alot, i have already set it up, just needa ask my friend to test it on his device now

Comment: okay, i tried it just now , it doesnt work, its still messed up

Comment: You should enlarge or reduce the size of the items

Comment: would there be another layout that would do similar thing with less problem? please check out the added image, even with a larger device  its still messed up

Answer (score 0):

Attribute android:layout_columnWeight is added in API level 21,try to use android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout with app:layout_columnWeight instead if your app was desired for supporting of Android 4.x.